# Fragments Viewpager different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, android-viewpager

I have a `FragmentActivity` that uses 2 different layouts depends on the screen size:

1. xLarge Landscape. The layout has 3 `LinearLayouts` which hold 1 fragments each.
2. Rest screens sizes. The layout has 1 `ViewPager` which holds all fragments.

The application crashes when the screen orientation changes in 10'' screen. It uses screen size 1 in landscape mode and size 2 in portrait mode.

The code:

```
public class RegistroAccionesPartidoActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static ArrayAdapter<Fragment> mFragmentArray;
private ViewPager mMyPager;
private Fragment1 mFragment1;

private Fragment2 mFragment2;
private Fragment3 mFragment3;
private MyFragmentAdapter mFragmentsAdapter;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTrasaction;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); 


    LinearLayout layoutFragment1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment1);


    if(layoutFragment1 == null) {

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mMyPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
        mFragmentArray = new ArrayAdapter<Fragment>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mFragmentsAdapter = new Fragment2Adapter(mFragmentManager);


        if(savedState == null) { 

            mFragment2 = new Fragment2(true);
            mFragment3 = new Fragment3();
            mFragment1 = new Fragment1(mIdPartido, mIdEquipoLocal, mIdEquipoVisitante);
        } else {

            mFragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedState, "fragment1");
            mFragment2 = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().
            getFragment(savedState,"fragment2");
            mFragment3 = (Fragment3) getSupportFragmentManager().
            getFragment(savedState, "fragment3");
        }


        mFragmentArray.add(mFragment1);
        mFragmentArray.add(mFragment2);
        mFragmentArray.add(mFragment3);

        mDatosPartidoPager.setAdapter(mFragmentsAdapter);

        mDatosPartidoPager.setCurrentItem(1);


       } else { // xLarge Version

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTrasaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        if(savedState == null) {
            mFragment1 = new Fragment1();
            mFragment2 = new Fragment2();
            mFragment3 = new Fragment3();


        } else {
            mFragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().
                getFragment(savedState, "fragment1");

            mFragment2 = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().
                getFragment(savedState,"fragment2");
            mFragment3 = (Fragment3) getSupportFragmentManager().
                getFragment(savedState, "fragment3");
    }
    mFragmentTrasaction.add(R.id.fragment1, mFragment1);
    mFragmentTrasaction.add(R.id.fragment2, mFragment2);
    mFragmentTrasaction.add(R.id.fragment3, mFragment3);
    mFragmentTrasaction.commit();
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment2" , 
        mFragment2);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment3", 
        mFragment3);

    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"fragment1", 
        mFragment1);

    }
}
```

XLarge Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The rest screen sizes layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_pager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have 2 diffrent crashes according to the order of the screen change:

1. Starting on landscape, the error message is:

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x...... for Fragment2*

1. When I start on portrait, the error message is:

> *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Fragment1*

Sorry for the large question. I just tried to be clear on explaining my problem.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** In big devices (like 10'') Landscape mode uses xLarge Layout and portrait mode uses the other layout.

Answer (score 0):

for me (inside the XLarge Layout) the nested LinearLayout-Elements mixing horizontal and vertical orientation look quite strange. Please have a closer look, if you intented the nesting this way.

Greetings,
Wolfgang

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake when i adapted my code for better explanation. It is not in the original code.